# command seperated values is failing in cursor and showing "invalid number" in plsql

Tags: plsql

```
 insert into test values(prodlist,'365,367');


 CURSOR CUSTOMER IS
    SELECT CUST_ID
      FROM customer a, custacctrel b
     WHERE a.CUST_ID = b.CUSTO_ID
       AND b.PRODCODE IN (VAR_L_PRODUCT_LIST);

select prod_list into var_l_product_list from test;
```

IN the above code i have inserted the productcode in single column value so that in cursor i can get the customer having either product codes. but it is showing invalid number. how to solve this.
the data type for product code is varchar2(30). I want to use in simple way.

Comment: How should `365,367` be a number?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use in simple way.

Sometimes wishes don't come true, as code that follows isn't that *simple*.

```
   CURSOR CUSTOMER IS
      SELECT CUST_ID
        FROM customer a, custacctrel b
       WHERE     a.CUST_ID = b.CUSTO_ID
             AND b.PRODCODE IN (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (prod_list,
                                                      '[^,]+',
                                                      1,
                                                      COLUMN_VALUE)
                                  FROM test
                                       CROSS JOIN
                                       TABLE (
                                          CAST (
                                             MULTISET (
                                                    SELECT LEVEL
                                                      FROM DUAL
                                                CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                                             REGEXP_COUNT (prod_list,
                                                                           ',')
                                                           + 1)
                                                AS SYS.odcinumberlist)));
```

---

There might be variations (simpler or more complex), but - basically - you'll have to split `PROD_LIST` into rows so that you could use those values in cursor.

---

Though, if there's exactly one row in `test` table, perhaps you could do it simpler as

```
   CURSOR CUSTOMER IS
      SELECT CUST_ID
        FROM customer  a
             JOIN custacctrel b ON a.cust_id = b.custo_id
             JOIN temp t
                ON INSTR (',' || t.prod_list || ',', ',' || b.prodcode || ',') > 0;
```